# Why is my glass looked like this? , I follow Blender guru's Part 3 Level 3, but ended up having this kind of glass

Tags: texturing, light, transparency, glass

[image: Blender guru part 3 level 3 tutorial]

I've watched Blender guru's Part 3, Level 3, but ended up with this kind of problem that also encountered by the others as well, but they've already solved it and I followed their instruction, but still didn't get the glass they have

I've also followed some of the answers given herein community but still didn't get what I expected.

[image]

Comment: what problem are you talking about? The strange thing is that your IOR is at 0, yet it still makes glass... for glass the IOR should be at something like 1.45

Comment: when I set the value of IOR to 1.45 the outcome is slightly becoming good, but there is still some solid gray color to models, wait I'll edit the post with that gray color.

Comment: it seems normal to me, it looks like the reflection of the world color, maybe give your world another color or an HDRI image

Comment: I haven't touched that since using blender 2.8, All I did was followed the tutorial. what should I do about that, In my World shader all I have is a Gray color with the strength of 1, my problem is why mine is different when all I did was to follow the tutorial?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, there are some white streaks but it might be some planes you've used as lights or some Area lights? Maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I've already uploaded it thank you. try to render it that's where I got the difference between the tutorial and my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not obvious because your cup seems almost normal but actually you have some flipped normals, go in *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> > *Recalculate Normals*, it will fix your problem.

Comment: I finally got it! Thank you! I already think of inverting the normals, but still didn't get the glass I want, but the thing is the first time I tried that is my IOR is set to 0, now and the moment you told me to change that I haven't tried inverting it again. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Not much of an answer, but. I just wanted to show you what you can get using EEVEE instead of CYCLES.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'll try that too thank you!

Comment: so is it possible to fix this transparency problem in Eevee?

Comment: yes, its possible.